# Getting rep from tag edits shows blank/null reason for gaining rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

I just edited the wiki for [**[magicka]**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magicka) and got some rep for it.  When I viewed where my recent rep came from, it looked like this:

[image: blank rep descriptions]

There is no reason at all, just a blank space.  Mystery rep.

Poking around some more, I also found this on my recent rep graph page:
[image: reason shows as null]

Comment: ok will sort it out, good catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed now, was a fairly involved change.