# Tag wikis should be referenced with a more useful title

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, tag-wiki, information-display

Reputation gained from tag wiki changes makes them show up in the reputation graph on the [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135441/martin-buberl?tab=reputation). But instead of something like "tag wiki foobar", the reputation listing shows "null":

[image: points for null values]

Maybe this problem also occurs in other places where a links to a tag wiki are shown.

Comment: Related: [the envelope report doesn't even show a thing for these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77739/getting-rep-from-tag-edits-doesnt-show-the-reason-in-the-recent-rep-tab-thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed a while back, was part of the change that fixed [Getting rep from tag edits shows blank/null reason for gaining rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77739/getting-rep-from-tag-edits-doesnt-show-the-reason-in-the-recent-rep-tab-thing)