# Should I get the +2 bonus twice for suggesting a tag wiki?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

I noticed (now that [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77739/getting-rep-from-tag-edits-shows-blank-null-reason-for-gaining-rep) has been fixed) that you basically get two +2 rep bonuses for suggesting a tag wiki: one for the wiki, one for the wiki excerpt. Is this really intended? It seems odd to me, since I suggested both at the same time from the same screen. Does it work the same way with posts: do I get +2 for suggesting an edit to a post's title, another +2 for suggesting an edit to the body, and another +2 for suggesting an edit to the tags?

[image]

Comment: You can only get 1000 points from edits so it's only going to get you to that limit marginally quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excerpt and the body are, for the intents and purposes of the system, completely different posts. For example, the body for that tag is [15930](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/15930/revisions) and the excerpt is [15931](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/15931/revisions).

This does mean twice the bonus for users who suggest a brand new tag wiki that gets approved. Personally, I'm fairly comfortable with that, though, and don't see too much abuse for it.